# Tic Tac Toe program not identifying the winner

Tags: java

I have this slight problem with my Tic Tac Toe program. I have a nested counter checking for vertical and horizontal wins with the X piece (I haven't done it for O yet). For some reason, it never ends, allowing me to place more and more pieces.

For some context, here are some snippets of code.

```
public static void game (String winner, Board pointer)
{ 
    boolean win = false;
    int turnCount = 1;
    winner = "Tie";
    while (win == false || turnCount < 9)
    {
        int row = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(pointer.getName1() + ", it is your turn. " + "\n" + "What row would you like your 'x' to be in?"));
        int col = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What column would you like it to be in?"));
        pointer.play[row] [col] = pointer.x;
        SpotCheck1(winner, pointer, row, col);
        System.out.println(BoardStat(pointer));
        winCheck(win, pointer, winner);
        int row2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(pointer.getName2() + ", it is your turn. " + "\n" + "What row would you like your 'o' to be in?")); 
        int col2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What column would you like it to be in?"));
        SpotCheck2(winner, pointer, row2, col2);
        pointer.play[row2] [col2] = pointer.o;
        System.out.println(BoardStat(pointer));
        winCheck(win, pointer, winner);
        turnCount++;
    }
    //return winner;
}

public static void winCheck (boolean win, Board pointer, String winner)
{
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++)
    {
        if ( pointer.play [counter] [1].compareTo(pointer.x) > 0 && pointer.play [counter] [2].compareTo(pointer.x) > 0 && pointer.play [counter] [3].compareTo(pointer.x) > 0)
        {
            win = true;
            winner = pointer.getName1();
            win(winner, pointer);
        }          
        else if (pointer.play [1] [counter].compareTo(pointer.x) > 0 && pointer.play [2] [counter].compareTo(pointer.x) > 0 && pointer.play [3] [counter].compareTo(pointer.x) > 0)
        {
            win = true;
            winner = pointer.getName1();
            win(winner, pointer);
        }
    }
    //return win;

}
```

SpotChecks 1 and 2 are the ways to check if a player has already placed a piece. The problem, I think, is in the WinCheck method. If anybody can help me out, that'd be great! First post, apologies if I did something wrong.

Comment: As a tip: move away from ```static``` and move the state you're keeping (outside your while loop) to instance fields.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the parameter `win` in the method `winCheck` and you are expecting that this changed the local variable `win` in method `game`. But that's not the case - Java passes method parameters by value, so the `win` in `winCheck` is a copy and any changes do not reflect back. You can make the return type of method `winCheck` a `boolean`.

```
public static boolean winCheck (boolean win, Board pointer, String winner)
{
    // Other code is unchanged

    return win;
}
```

And in your `game` method you change any invocation of the method `winCheck` to:

```
win = winCheck(...);
```

Comment: He could box the boolean, Boolean and then achieve what he wants.

Comment: @Underbalanced A `java.lang.Boolean` is immutable so it wouldn't achieve what he wants.

Comment: I learn something new everyday. Did not know that about Boolean. The only time i use Boxed values is in Maps, List.